# How to change the thumbnail size to a specific category?

Tags: categories, thumbnails

I am using thumbnail on my blog posts.
I added the following code in my **functions.php** for that purpose

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');  
set_post_thumbnail_size( 328, 228, true );
```

It's working fine and all thumbnails are **328 x 228**

Now I want to change the thumbnail size only for a specific category **ID is 9.**

Post under category ID 9's thumbnails must be **100 x 150.**

how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just use conditionals:

```
if ( in_category( '9' )) {
    // different size for one category
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 100, 150, true ); 
} elseif ( in_category( array( '5', '7' ) )) {
    // different size for multiple categories
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 200, true ); 
} else {
    // default size
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 328, 228, true ); 
}
```

**Reference:**

- [Conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)
- [in_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category)

Comment: thanks for that. I've added `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');  // enabling thimbnail on post summary - riffaz
if ( in_category( '11' )) {    
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 135, 10, true ); // different size for one category
} else {    
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 328, 228, true ); // default size
}` on my **functions.php** it's cropping the image width as **135 and 328** bout not the height. height is fixed as 197. how can I force to crop?

Comment: You might want to read this: [add_image_size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)

Comment: Are you sure that this code would automatically resize images on upload for all three image sizes? I don't think so. Because when the server parses the PHP, it will only collect the true condition size into the global `$_wp_additional_image_sizes` array. Meaning, when uploading a new image, it will only resize it to size in `else` condition (because there is no global `$post` at the moment, so `in_category()` will always return `false`). I have not tested this, though.